# Building an Air app for desktop@2015, any disadvantages?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Since I'm familiar with AS3, I'm planning to build a desktop app using Air, and I'd like to not run into limitations, I never developed a full blown app for desktop using Air, only small apps and others for mobile.

The idea of this app is to be similar to an IDE, with some visual management, think of the design view of Flex, something like that. But not that big, a smaller/reduced version of that.

I'm asking this because I don't remember seeing any app like that built in Air, and I wonder if there is a good reason, or not.

If for example someone says: "use Java, its better", please tell me why, and more importantly, what things I can do in Java for desktop that Air just wont allow me to.

Comment: AIR is very underperformant compared to other technology, which may or may not be a concern for you.

Comment: Are you talking about framerate?.

Comment: Not just the frame rate - plenty of processing things are very slow compared to other languages.

Comment: Depends on so many factors - like what other languages do you know/are willing to learn. What features do you need. What is your development time frame. What platforms do you need to support. What is the projected life span of the app. Toolchain, QA, active coding community. Do you need the dev tool to be free (no licensing or subscription)

Comment: I will ignore the fact that I'm receiving advise from a tomato :p. To answer your questions: 

- I don't plan on learning a new language to make this, unless it's impossible to make it with Air, which I think is not the case. 
- features, not much really, only a drag and drop of png/jpg files into the editor to make things easier.
- I don't have a time frame, but I'd like to take less than 2 or 3 months, it's a personal project.
- Only Windows so far, maybe Mac in the future, not a priority.
- No idea about the life span, not much anyway.

Comment: The only downside is that you might not find a code base that would fit perfectly your project and so you might have to write everything yourself. As opposed to the eclipse project for example which is used as a base for many IDE development. That's the only downside I can think of other than that AIR for desktop has no limitation.

Comment: Personally, I would use Qt – but there is a learning curve so if that is not of interest, then that's out. But Qt is pretty exciting, feature-wise, and is actively being developed, unlike the whole AIR-Flex-AS3 thing which seems at EOL and in mostly maintenance/niche market. Adobe clearly does not see much future for it, took out the visual design tool in FB, etc.  (just my opinion ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO AIR is extremely powerful and if you combine Stage3D + [Native Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) you can do almost everything with a good performance. I have been working in several projects for desktop, iOS and Android and using [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) + [Feathers](http://feathersui.com) + [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org) + creating my own native extensions (plus there is a lot of free/open source/commercial) was possible to achieve all my (and clients) goals.

Also, there is a huge (ActionScript/AIR) community sharing knowledge and helping each other, several open source frameworks (for games, 2D, 3D, animations, GUI).

I have tried Objective-C, Swift and Java and of course, there is a lot of positive points, native performance, powerful IDE's, GUI integration, native components, etc.
It's a mix, if you need to have your app running in multi platform, I believe Adobe AIR is a good option, if not and you have the necessary knowledge to work using Objective-C/Java, use native.

Of course, it's all relative, I'm just trying to share some tips.